# Working with global window variable in mocha js from node

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, mocha.js, chai

I am new to js unit testing and I am trying to use mocha for my backbone contact manager tutorial that i found at [this github repo](https://github.com/dmytroyarmak/backbone-contact-manager/blob/gh-pages/app/js/app.js). However, i have a global window.ContactManager variable that I firsted wanted to test whether it exists and then test the router.on functionality inside the start function later. The variable looks like so:

```
  window.ContactManager = {
  Models: {},
  Collections: {},
  Views: {},

  start: function(data) {
    var contacts = new ContactManager.Collections.Contacts(data.contacts),
        router = new ContactManager.Router();

    router.on('route:home', function() {
      router.navigate('contacts', {
        trigger: true,
        replace: true
      });
    });

    router.on('route:showContacts', function() {
      var contactsView = new ContactManager.Views.Contacts({
        collection: contacts
      });
.....
```

My test that does not work: 
var expect = require ('chai').expect;

```
describe("Application", function() {
    it('creates a global variable for the name space ContactManager' , function () {
        expect(ContactManager).to.exist;
    })
});
```

How do I test and access a global window variable existence in mocha from running the tests in the console?

Comment: `expect(window.ContactManager).to.exist;` ?

Comment: yes. I thought a first test would be to test whether it exists and then test the router triggers inside the start function. Please see the edit

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are ignoring the difference between running JavaScript code in the browser and running JavaScript code in Node.

In the browser, the `window` name is a reference to the object which holds all your global variables. So when you do `foo = 1` in the outermost scope, you declare a global `foo`, which is also accessible as `window.foo`. Conversely, if you assign a new field like this: `window.bar = 1`, then you have a new global called `bar`.

In Node, your global object is accessed as `global`. So if you do `foo = 1` in the outermost scope, `foo` is also accessible as `global.foo`. And if you do `global.bar = 1`, you have a new global named `bar`.

Your code shows that you modify a `window` object, which does not appear to be a reference to the global object. Options:

1. Run Mocha in the browser instead of in Node. See [Mocha's documentation](http://mochajs.org/#running-mocha-in-the-browser).
2. Set your Node environment so that it mimics enough of a browser environment to satisfy node. Setting a global `window` variable to be a equal to `global` *might* be enough but I don't know Backbone enough to know whether Backbone will be happy with this.
3. Run your Backbone-based code in [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom). Jsdom provides realistic `window` and `document`, as if your code was running in a browser, but it has its limits. I don't know whether Backbone would be happy with those limits.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution would be to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/window-or-global

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
// in node, you'll get the global object instead of crashing by an error 
import root from 'window-or-global'

class MyComponent extends Component {

  // this method is only invoked in the browser environment 
  componentDidMount() {
    root.addEventListener(/*...*/)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    root.addEventListener(/*...*/)
  }

  render() {}

}

// Voilà. Enjoy your universal react component! ;) 
// No more 'window is not defined' errors when you render your component 
// on server side.
```

To install, run `npm install --save window-or-global`.

Running tests on server (for example with [mocha-webpack](https://github.com/zinserjan/mocha-webpack)) is way more faster than in a browser.